# Query de MySQL para sumar una columna y obtener el valor mayor de la suma de acuerdo al id de ese registro

Tags: mysql, sum

Buenos días espero me puedan ayudar con esto, necesito sumar el valor de la columna monto por cada persona y de esa sumatoria seleccionar el valor mayor, en la imagen esta el ejemplo mas detallado de lo que necesito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega que llevas al momento

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esta codigo

```
select Max(idVenta), idPersona, Max(nombre), sum(monto) as suma_monto
from su_tabla
group by idPersona
order by 4 desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de si el order by puede hacerse por el alias suma_monto, tu probaste esa consulta?